# Symfony 2 filesystem. Cant access to an AS400 (iSeries) repository (path, not database)

Tags: php, symfony, filesystems, iseries-navigator

I’m trying to get some .pdf from an AS400 (not a database, only a repository (windows) from the server) using filesystem from the symfony 2 controller (php), but I can’t get them. I’m guessing since the server has a login, do I need to pass the user and the password when creating the path?

The path actually is a simple one:

> \\ip\foldername\year\filename.pdf

(I had tried with this same path with a non as400 server and it works). The exact code example is this:

```php
$file = $codenum . '.pdf';
$path = '\\\\192.168.X.XXX\\folder1\\20' . $year . '\\' . $file;
$fs = new FileSystem();
if (!$fs->exists($path)) {
  //Do something
} else {
  //Do something
}
```

It’s not like I need to create a ODBC connection with the AS400 right?
One of the Symfony gitHub crew pointed me as a "access non-local filesystems" problem, but I still cant get enough info on the internet.

Any idea, hint or help would be great! :) 
Thanks a lot!

Urtzi.

Comment: try using a forward slash wherever you have a backslash

Comment: Thanks, @thanksd but that dosent seem to resolve the problem. Unless im writing the code wrong. Can you put an example please?. Thank you.

Comment: `$path = '//192.168.X.XXX/folder1/20' . $year . '/' . $file;`

Comment: Even if I put an IP its a mapped unit, so i guess it has to be with backslash. But anyway i tried your code and still no results :S I will look for a As400 connection or so. Thanks for the tip @thanksd appreciate the time.

Comment: Not sure about your main problem, but I'm 99% sure your code won't run with those backslashes as they're being interpreted as escape characters. If you need backslashes you'll have to double them up: `$path = '\\\\192.168.X.XXX\\folder1\\20' . $year . '\\' . $file;`

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry about that. I'm new to post messages on stackoverflow and the code turn out with double backslashes (at the beginning) after I post it, but in the original code I wrote like the last example you put (with four backlashes at the beginning). But doesn’t work either. To resume the problem, we could say there are 2 paths, one where I can reach the .pdf and the one where I can’t. The only difference is that the second one is an AS400 server, and the first one is normal windows server. Hard to explain hehe. Either way, thanks for the help @thanksd .

Comment: Do other methods than exists work? Are you able to access the file using PHP's built-in functions?